# How to handle the termination of an app-wide polling-routine?

Tags: android, polling, activity-lifecycle

I have kind of a tricky situation in my app.
I implemented a mechanism that contacts a remote server every 60 seconds to check if new data is available. If so, the new data is displayed in the app. So far so good.

I implemented the mechanism the following way:

- It gets started in the `onCreate()` method of my MainActivity.
- The polling routine gets stopped in my MainActivity's `onDestroy()` method.

This makes sure the polling is always active as long as the app is running. Also, **if I start another Activity from my MainActivity, I also want the polling to run.**

**My Problem:**

When I exit my application via the **Back-Button**, everything works fine and the polling stops. But when I exit my application through the **Home-Button, the polling routine stays alive** since `onDestroy()` of my MainActivity is not called, but I want it to stop.

If I change my code and stop the polling routine in the `onPause()` method of my MainActivity, I have the problem that the **polling also gets stopped when I launch a new Activity.**

**What I want:**

I want the polling to run as long as my Application (not my MainActivity) is in foreground / visible to the user. As soon as the User exits the application by pressing the Home-Button from anywhere in the App, or by pressing the Back-Button from the MainActivity, I want the polling to stop.

**ADDITIONAL:**

**I also do not want to restart and stop the service everytime I switch Activities.** Since the user of my Application will switch Activitys very often, this would just be a lot of overhead. Furthermore, I want the "refresh"-cycle to be exactly 60 seconds. I cannot guarantee that when I always restart the service and stop it again. It needs to be started once when the app gets started, and stopped when the app is no longer in foreground.

**How to achieve that?**

**Isn't there some kind of simple way to check when the App is in foreground and when its hidden / closed?**

This is my singelton-polling mechanism:

```
private Timer t;
private static Updater instance;

protected Updater() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static Updater getInstance() {

    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Updater();
    }

    return instance;
}

public void startPollingRoutine(int interval, int delay) {      

    t = new Timer();

    // Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            update(); // some asynctask that does the updating
        }

    }, delay, interval);
}

public static void stopPollingRoutine() {
    t.cancel();
}
```

In code:

```
Updater.getInstance().startPollingRoutine(60000, 0);
Updater.getInstance().stopPollingRoutine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help and time.
**I finally found a solution by myself that meets all my requirements.**

I followed this tutorial to make it work: **http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html**

The basic Idea is to extend the Application class and **keep reference** to how many Activitys are "alive" at a certain time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way how to handle it is to create some BaseActivity which all activities will extend. And to perform this actions in onResume/onPause. Or you can try using services.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but it does not meet my requirements. (See "ADDITIONAL" in my question)

Comment: You can save at preferences last scan timestamp, and start timer when you need it

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a service and trigger it in your main class that service will be triggered unless you explicitly stop it on destroy means onBackpressed()/onDetroy() and  let it run in onPause() method

Comment: Yes, but when to stop the service? It is not enough to stop the service in onDestroy() since it wont be called when the home-button is pressed. onPause() is also not an option since the polling should not stop when a new Activity is started.

Comment: more over on this you can also use broadcast receiver 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a singleton, and let it have a counter variable. Increase it when you send intent to start a new activity, and decrease it in the onPause.
Than you can tell if the polling has to stop; when the counter in the singleton is zero.

Comment: that wont work because you can press the home button from any activity so if you are 3 activities in and the user hits the home the polling wont stop like he wants

Comment: I am already using a singelton, the only question is how to stop it that it meets my requirements.

Comment: I meent, decrease it from onPause of every activity.

Comment: @hakanostrom so what happens when the user hits the home button when the count is 3??